# O renderer2 do angular possui algum método para clicar em algum elemento?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um modal bootstrap que em determinado momento do meu código TS eu devo fecha-lo.

Atualmente pra fechar esse modal eu utilizo uma variável local no botão de fechar do modal e uso viewChild pra clicar nele:

```
<button #fechaModalAlteracaoAnuncio type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>

@ViewChild('fechaModalAlteracaoAnuncio') fechaModalAlteracaoAnuncio: ElementRef;
```

E então na minha função:

```
salvaAlteracoesAnuncio() {

    this.fechaModalAlteracaoAnuncio.nativeElement.click();

}
```

Eu vi em alguns sites dizendo que acessar o DOM com `viewChild` não é seguro, que deveriamos usar o `Renderer2`. Porém, não encontrei nenhuma forma de realizar o click com o renderer.

Vocês conhecem alguma forma alternativa de fechar o modal através do TS?

Comment: Tenta utilizar `(click)` dentro de sua tag `button`. Então seu modelo ficaria. `<button ... (click)='funcaoFechar()'>`

Comment: Em um determinado momento da minha função salvaAlteracoesAnuncio eu devo fechar a modal, portanto o close da modal tem que ser feito através do TS não do html...

Comment: usando jquery ficaria assim `$('#idModal').modal('hide')`. E não esqueça de declara o `$` depois do imports `declare var $`

Comment: Eu quero fazer em angular!

Comment: Qual a lógica você quer fazer pra fechar a modal ? O Bootstrap é uma API que utiliza `jquery` na suas componentes. No final, quando você clicar no botão de fechar a chamada que será executada é essa.

Comment: Quero saber se é possível com o renderer do angular. Eu sei que o bootstrap usa jquery.